# When Will the Default Constructor of Service.svc in a WCF Service is executed?

Tags: c#, wcf

Here is a sample code

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service()
    {
      // here I am getting value from web.config 
      // using configurationManager which will be
      // changing frequently
    }

    //Method1
    ....
    //Method2
    .....

}
```

When will be the constructor of my service will be executed ? 
During the First request or On every request ?

Comment: it will be called whenever consumer make instance of service.

Answer (score 0):

afaik the constructor is called for every request/call to the service.

Also, when the web.config is *changed* the application pool will recycle if your application is hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you consume/call your WCF service through browser like below then every call create new object of service so execute your service default constructor.

Browser Call: .../pricedataservice/DataService.svc/web/GetHistoryData

but if you call service via adding reference to other project then it would be call/execute constructor only when you create object of service

Comment: I ll call the service from Mobile application using Javascript Ajax.. What would be the case then..?

Comment: yes, if you call service though Javascript Ajax then every time service default constructor execute